# Is there a trick to making "text-decoration-skip-ink" work properly so the underline doesn't touch the descending characters like lowercase "g"?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an underline that doesn't touch the letters that drop down like "g" or "j" and have found an article on text-decoration-skip-ink but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
.insta-title {
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: all;
}
```

If this isn't an option, could someone suggest a flexible way to create an underline like the one below?

Here's the website (the module in question is toward the bottom)
https://miles.birdhouse-demos.com/

Here's the article I was reading about this fancy CSS trick that isn't working:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset

[image: Chalk Underline]

Comment: _"text-decoration-skip-ink but it doesn't appear to be working"_ - you don't _have_ a text-decoration there, you have a border-bottom - totally different thing.

Comment: I think you mean [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink)? `skip-ink` won't work globally because right now it is Firefox only.

Answer (score -1):

An example with the `<a>` as an inline-block element. Use the padding for the distance between text and border-bottom.

```css
a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  /* dotted,dashed,solid,double,groove,ridge,inset,outset */
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #22a;
}
a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #22a;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

```html
Lorum <a href="" class="udl">fghij klmnop xyz</a> Lorum.
```